# Youtube Data API Quickstart Code Always Run Cancel Function

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I ran YouTube Data API's [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android) code example and an error occurred: **null** from `onCancelled()` method. When I wrote a debug log, `ChannelListResponse` result did not executed. What can I do to solve problem?

```java
@Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        return getDataFromApi();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mLastError = e;
        cancel(true);
        return null;
    }
}
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "inside getDataFromApi: " + mService);
    // Get a list of up to 10 files.
    List<String> channelInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    YouTube.Channels.List request = mService.channels()
            .list("snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
    ChannelListResponse result = request.setForUsername("GoogleDevelopers").execute();
    Log.d(TAG, "getDataFromApi: " + request);
    Log.d(TAG, "getDataFromApi: " + result);
    List<Channel> channels = result.getItems();
    if (channels != null) {
        Channel channel = channels.get(0);
        channelInfo.add("This channel's ID is " + channel.getId() + ". " +
                "Its title is '" + channel.getSnippet().getTitle() + ", " +
                "and it has " + channel.getStatistics().getViewCount() + " views.");
    }
    return channelInfo;
}
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    mProgress.hide();
    if (mLastError != null) {
        if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                    ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                            .getConnectionStatusCode());
        } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                    MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                    + mLastError.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack trace (as text).

Comment: I create a OAuth client ID and its solved the problem. Thank you.. @stvar